# For what is need such a form of unset?

Tags: php, unset

Today I try this:

```
(unset) $myVar;
```

This form is accepted in php 5.2, but where it can be used?

P.S. Actually variable will not be destroyed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

**Example #2 Using (unset) casting**

> (unset) casting is often confused with the unset() function. (unset)
>   casting serves only as a NULL-type cast, for completeness. It does not
>   alter the variable it's casting.

```
<?php
$name = 'Felipe';

var_dump((unset) $name);
var_dump($name);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
NULL
string(6) "Felipe"
```

Comment: The answer was in manual...I'm ashamed ) Anyway, can you provide some real use-cases for it ?

Comment: Are there any fundamental differences with var_dump(null) ?

Comment: *sidenote* I cant think of a situation/real use-cases to use it. But its there for completeness as it says.

Comment: @ClémentMalet **yes**, its NULL'ing the variable but not altering it, your just var_dump'ing null, its completely different. Like `var_dump(chr(65));` vs `var_dump('A');`, different.